# Replace LightDM with MDM on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: lightdm, 13.10, display-manager

I'm trying to replace LighDM with MDM on Ubuntu 13.10, but there already is package in Ubuntu sources called mdm. It's not display manager, but "The Middleman System"...

So the PPA install doesn't work. I tried installing .deb package and it changed login screen, but gave me an error message after login and then X stopped. I had to revert back...

Any ideas on how to install mdm on Ubuntu 13.10...???

Answer (score 1):

The bug was fixed...

Installed MDM using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/mint
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mdm mdm-themes
```

MDM is working just fine.

Comment: I'm using VMWare and this fixed the problem.